# Speed of light of a falling ladder

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

The classic problem of a ladder that is leaning on a wall, if a ladder starts to fall down by sliding against the wall, will the top of the ladder ever reach the speed of light? I am confused about this topic. The triangle is assumed to be a right triangle. My professor asked the class this question and I cannot intuitively  solve it. I understand that this "should" occur when

$$x (\text{ distance from the wall }) = L \text{  length of ladder} $$

Which then the rate at which the top of the ladder is falling "should" be infinity. Obviously this is incorrect.

Comment: What sets the speed of the ladder falling?  It is sliding on the side of the building and accelerating under gravity, is the contact point on the ground moving uniformly, or what?

Comment: As a maths question, you need to be explicit as to a model you are assuming and how it leans to the infinite speed. As a physics question, we can show why the model is non-physical.

Comment: Are you assuming that the top of the ladder remains in contact with the wall all the way down? That won't happen if it's falling freely. What forces are being applied to hold the ladder against the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hawaiian Rolls Your problem is stated differently from [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/ladder.html):

> "The classic problem of a ladder that is leaning on a wall, if a ladder starts to fall down by sliding against the wall, will the top of the ladder ever reach the speed of light?"

I don't think your professor said "sliding against the wall" the whole time because it would be incorrect.

Your version of the problem does not state clearly if the ladder is required to always stay in contact with the wall while sliding down.

If it is required, the velocities in the horizontal direction and the vertical direction are constrained by a relationship involving gravitation. In this case, there is no way you can have a constant horizontal speed at all.

In the [other problem](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/ladder.html) that Toby Mak mentioned, the constant horizontal speed will cause the ladder to pull off away from the wall immediately.

In fact, at time $t = 0$, the horizontal speed is already greater than the vertical speed. Thus, immediately after $t=0$, the horizontal speed will pull the ladder away from the wall.

Comment: You are correct that the ladder should not be against the wall at every moment, but I am unclear what you mean by at  $t = 0$ the horizontal speed is already greater than the vertical speed. From what I can grasp with my knowledge is that the related rates between the $x$ (horizontal) and $y$ (vertical) is that y changes, and the vertical speed, as the horizontal speed changes. So if the horizontal speed at 0 is greater than the vertical speed then at time 0 you no longer have a ladder against the wall at $t=0$

Comment: I based on the assumption that the horizontal component of the velocity, say $v_x(t)$, is always a constant. You cannot have a continuous function $v_x(t=0) = 0$ and $v_x(t>0) = c \not=0$ because it contradicts  the assumption.

Comment: Even if you want to be a little bit mathematically sloppy by allowing $v_x$ to jump from $0$ to $c$ in an infinitesimal delta time, this would require infinite acceleration, which is impossible. Let's say in the infinitesimal interval of time at $t=0$, assume $v_x$ jumps from 0 to $c$. Then, $v_y$ has to respond by jumping from 0 to some value. But before $v_y$ has any time to change,  the top of the ladder has already been pulled off from the wall and the formula that determines the $y$ velocity becomes invalid.

Comment: I see where you are getting at.

Answer (score 2):

[This website](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/ladder.html) here gives a good explanation on why the falling ladder does not fall at an infinite speed. Hint: the triangle is only **assumed** to be a right triangle — it might not be in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for giving me reputation (whoever it is)!

Comment: if only the guy fixed his images!!

Comment: So I'm not sure if you or @Hoc Ngo would be able to explain to me, but if I were to use a machine to do this experiment (like a rail system that pulls the bottom at a constant horizontal speed) does the experiment fail because we cannot assume that the horizontal speed will remain constant throughout the entire duration of the experiment. That is to say that $\frac{dy}{dt} \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow$ length of the ladder will never be true because $\frac{dx}{dt}$ will not remain constant? If so, if the mechanism is design to just that what prevents it from doing so?

Comment: Perhaps the following experiment will help you understand the constant $x$ velocity. Imagine there is a road that is 4 meters wide that runs through a wall that is 10 meters tall.  So engineers have to cut out a 4-meter section of the wall to clear the road.  Now, someone is crazy enough to put a 10-meter wide ladder in the road against the wall.  The ladder blocks the road  and 3 m of the wall on either side.  A car is traveling at a constant speed of 50 km/h, zipping through the wall at time $t=0$. Only in this case do you have a constant $v_x(t) = c$ for $t \ge0$.

Comment: In fact, if you consider the time $t>=0$ only, then this experiment satisfies the condition that $v_x(t)$ is constant for all $t \ge0$.  In this experiment, the ladder will be pulled along with the car; it cannot slide down the wall. Thus, it is wrong to use the Pythagorean rule to compute the vertical component of the velocity. Hence, the formula for $v_y$ computed from the Pythagorean formula is completely bogus.